# Problems on RIGHT function on Sharepoint

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, formula

I have a calculated field which is filled in automatically thanks to a simple formula:

```
=(X*X*Z/162-Y*Y*Z/162)*X
```

This generate a number like: 1.637.037
I have a problem on adding RIGHT function to remove first 4 char from right to left and leave the number like 1.637 or like 1.637,03 by adding the comma.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

**Update**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is your column value always has the format like: x.xxx.xxx? 1 digit then 3 digits and 3 digits??

Comment: Yes, is a calculated column. Example: `=(150,00*150,00*6000,00/162-20,00*20,00*6000,00/162)*2`
generate 
`1.637.037`

Answer (score 0):

May be you need LEFT function?

RIGHT will extract number of characters from the right side.

To remove last 4 characters from right - try to use formula:

```
=LEFT([column],LEN([column])-3)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: No, in my example I need to remove 4 char from right.

1.637.037 to 1.637 (or 1.637,00)

Comment: @MarkR you need to use LEFT function to leave left part and exclude right part.

Comment: @MarkR I've updated my answer.

Comment: It doesn't work. It convert it like this:
`1.637.37 to 1637037,03703`

Comment: @MarkR look on my screens. As you can see It does not convert to 1637037,03703. It removes last 4 characters from right.

Comment: I updated my screen on the main post, check it please :)

Comment: @MarkR Please use `,` instead of `;` in formula. Should be `=LEFT(KgTeoRien, LEN(KgTeoRien)-3)`

Comment: If I use comma, it gives me a Microsoft error. Formula works only with `;`

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14)#remove-characters-from-text

Comment: Yes I know it but if I use comma, the error says "The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported." On excel formula in Italy I use `;` separator.

Comment: I tryed to use `=LEFT(KgTeoRien, LEN(KgTeoRien)-3)` on a not calculated table, and it give me a `#VALUE!` error

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your column name is `Column` of Type "Single Line of Text" and always has the format like `x.xxx.xxx`,

Try using below formula:

```
=LEFT([Column],INT(FIND(".",[Column],3)-1))
```

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in calculated column formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Change the **The data type returned from this formula is** of your calculated column to **Single line of text** from column settings.

Comment: In italy Sharepoint convert comma to semicolon automatically.
Anyway your formula doesn't work it show me a #VALUE! error on the Sharepoint table.

Comment: You need to convert your previous calculated column (column in attached image to question) to be of type single line of text instead of number.

Comment: I done this but it give me the same #VALUE! error.

Comment: Change the data type for both calculated column (previous and new). Are there any blank values in your previous column for some list items?

Comment: I can still see that "Number" selected for "The data type returned from this formula is" option (this option is below formula in calculated column settings).

Comment: I don't added in the screenshot but I've tested it with text value on both, but the error is the same.